# Set limit for b2Body class object moving in coco2d iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have one object of b2Body class. But I was it to move just say 25% of the screen from bottom. But it keeps moving though i set boundries.

Another option was to use setPosition once i reach that condition but in documentation this method exists but while implementation it throws error.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you,

Ankita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add CCColorLayer and put b2Body into it. It will move for that layer only. You can give x,y, heigh and width for layer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls) a great tutorial that explains the basics of box2D demonstrated using cocos2d for drawing. It specifically shows how to make physical boundaries for the screen, which i think is a better way of achieving what you want to do than "interfering" with the box2d world by setting positions and forces directly.

Comment: This is for a complete game. I want body just for particular object. If you take example of this game. I want just the object Pad to have some boundries for moving.

Comment: @Ankita my bad in that case, i'll probably remove this answer. Anyway, why are you talking about some sort of wall breaker style pad? In that case did you consider checking for the position on input and maybe not applying the movement if it's moving outside of it's bounds

Comment: Yes i checked by checking it's x and y value but no luck. Can you please give me any approach you think would work?

Comment: @Ankita when the Pad is out of it's bounds, try Pad.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(0, 0));